# how to use context in django

Tags: python, django

I'm a Django newbie and I have a problem. I'm trying to make my Webapplication a little bit more dynamic. So I want to create the data in the view and set it with Context() in the html document. Here is what I'm trying:

This is the View:

```
def test(request):

c = Context({"data": "{ label: 'Abulia', count: 10, start: 0, end: 10, radius: 10 }, { label: 'Betelgeuse', count: 20, start: 10, end: 20, radius: 20 }"})
t = get_template('graphtest.html')
html = t.render(c)
return HttpResponse(html)
```

and here is the part of my html document where it should be used:

```
var dataset = [ {{data}} ];
```

But it doesn't work.
Can someone tell me why and help me how I can make something like this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Simply put, a *Context* is simply a dictionary that you send to the template. The keys are then available as variables in the template.

Here's an example:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def test(request):
   ctx = {"data": "{ label: 'Abulia', count: 10, start: 0, end: 10, radius: 10 }, { label: 'Betelgeuse', count: 20, start: 10, end: 20, radius: 20 }"}
   return render(request, 'graphtest.html', ctx)
```

In your template:

```
var dataset = [ {{ data|escapejs }} ];
```

Use [`escapejs`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#escapejs) so that your value is escaped properly for javascript.

Comment: Ah I thought it is just a string. But your answer doesn't work for me. My Code looks like this: `def graphtest(request): c = {"data": "{ label: 'Abulia', count: 10, start: 0, end: 10, radius: 10 }, { label: 'Betelgeuse', count: 20, start: 10, end: 20, radius: 20 }"} return render(request, 'graphtest.html', c)` And the HTML: `var dataset = [ {{data|escapejs}} ];`

Comment: Again your answer didn't work! Can you explain it again and in a better way?